# Find and replace all strings in body, but ignore attributes with string value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Javascript/jQuery, I would like to find and replace all instances of "foo" to bar, but ignore any instances of "foo" that happen to be attribute values.

Example:

```
<p><a class="foo" id="foo" href="foo.html">foo</a>foo</a></p>
```

Should become

```
<p><a class="foo" id="foo" href="foo.html"><span class="fixed">bar</span></a></p>
```

This example is the problem I am running into....

`<h3><a id="foo" name="foo">About foo</a></h3>`

In that example, the attributes of the link get changed too

Comment: Then just replace the text content instead of inner HTML.

Comment: Do you need to handle `<span>f</span>oo`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, just looking to replace if it finds the exact string 'foo'

Comment: This example is the problem I am running into....

`<h3><a id="foo" name="foo">About foo</a></h3>`

In that example, the attributes of the link get changed too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.html(function)` `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/foo/g` and replacement string `"bar"`. If `this` within callback function does not contain `.childNodes` return `text` argument with `.replace(/foo/g, "bar")` chained, else iterate child nodes of element, match node where `.nodeName` is `#text`, replace `.textContent` of matched node. Use `Node.replaceChild()` to replace matched `#text` node with `<span>` element.

```js
$("body *").html(function(_, text) {
  if (!this.children.length) {
    return text.replace(/foo/g, '<span class="fixed">bar</span>')
  }
  else {
    var el = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
      var node = el.childNodes[i];
      if (node.nodeName === "#text") {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.textContent = node.textContent.replace(/foo/g, "bar");
        span.className = "fixed";
        node.parentNode.replaceChild(span, node);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<p><a class="foo" id="foo" href="foo.html">foo</a>foo</p>
<h3><a id="foo" name="foo">About foo</a></h3>
```

Comment: When I use that snippet, all the HTML within is stripped out, which I believe is because .text() is being used instead of .html()

Comment: @Hochmania See updated post.

Comment: Fixes one problem, but the span is inserted as text, instead of HTML.  I want to wrap the string in a span, but unofortunately the span comes out as text.

Comment: What do you mean? Original Question is to replace text, not create element, yes? What happens to text node having `.textContent` set to `"foo"` that is child node of `<p>` element?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. In short, need to find string 'foo' and replace with '<span class="fixed">bar</span>'. 

Issue I have run into is if 'foo' exists in a HTML element class or id, the JS is replacing it and breaking markup.

Comment: @Hochmania See updated post.